# Private WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf

I'm kind of a newb to WCF Web Services and have created a service.

Here is what I'm after:

- If someone vists http://somesite.com/Poo.svc they are rejected straight off the bat (404 or something)
- Only I can add a reference to the service in VS.

What I'm after is making the WCF service totally private.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a machine certificate to your machine, and use that certificate to authenticate yourself against the service. Anyone who cannot present that certificate will be rejected.

Read the [How To – Use Certificate Authentication and Message Security in WCF calling from Windows Forms](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=How%20Tos) article on Codeplex for detailed instructions on how to do this.

However, this won't prevent others from trying to add a service reference in Visual Studio. Except for not telling anyone about the service endpoint, there's really not much you can do to prevent that - at least not on the service level. You'd almost have to reject all incoming requests to that URL on a firewall or something.